# deleted migration file keeps coming back Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, version-control, migration

I have 2 versions of the same migration (bad habit, I know). I deleted old version many times, but after restarting my project (or do something with it, like rake db:test:prepare), the file shows up in my migrate folder. When I run rake db:migrate, it will complain about multiple migrations with the same name.

How can I delete a migration file completely? Is there a registry that I need to remove to prevent it from coming back?

Comment: What source control are you using? Sounds more like that could be restoring the file than anything rails does.

Comment: I am using Git. I added these deletion to my commits but they kept coming back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git add` only adds new and changed files, it doesn't remove deleted ones. To delete:

```
git rm db/migrate/<filename>
```

or if you have already deleted it from the filesystem:

```
git add -u
```

Comment: @AdamNYC Well, that's why I asked if you'd committed the delete :p

Comment: Came and stole the answer from the guys that did the work. =)

Answer (score 2):

Are you updating from a repo? I don't see how the original file could be restored otherwise.

You can also delete the entry from the schema_migration table, but that just tracks if it's been run or not (IIRC).

Comment: I am pretty sure I add delete file to my commits. Many commits later, the same issue still pops up. I also checked schema.rb in db folder but it just keep the latest update and does not show older updates.

Comment: Does the file appear in the repo? The migration file won't be re-created (AFAIK) from anything you'd do in Rails.

Comment: Hi Dave, I just deleted the file again. How do I find out if a file shows up in past commits or branches?

Comment: What SCCS? Are you sure you're committing the deleted file? Also, with two files with the same name (not sure what you mean by that either) seems like it'd be easy to get confused.

Comment: I have XXX_create_my_table (old version) and YYY_create_my_table (new version). Thanks for your follow-up. I'll try jimworm's suggestion.